# Let $f: K \rightarrow R$ be a ring homomorphism, where $K$ is a field and $R$ is a non-zero commutative ring with unity. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a problem in proving this map to be one-one. It is not said anything about the relationship about $K$ and $R$. Or is it not necessary that they be related somehow. Please help.

Comment: The kernel of a ring homomorphism is an ideal, and a field has no proper ideals. So either $f$ is constant or it is injective. But $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$, so only injectivity is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $f(x)=f(y)$ with $x,y\in K$ and $x\neq y$. Then, if $z=x-y$, $f(z)=0$ with $z\neq 0$. But$$1=f(1)=f\left(z\times z^{-1}\right)=f(z)\times f(z^{-1})\text,$$which is impossible, since $f(z)=0$.

Comment: Okk thanks sir. I got the point.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a ring homomorphism $f$ is 1-1 if and only if $\ker f=\{0\}$; what are the ideals of $K$?

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false: consider the unique morphism from a field to the zero ring.

**Edit.** The above lines answer the question

> Let $f: K \rightarrow R$ be a ring homomorphism, where $K$ is a field and $R$ is a commutative ring with unity. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one,

which was the first version. The point to understand is: Why (in commutative algebra) do we require $0\ne1$ for domains (and in particular for fields), but not for rings? The standard answer is:

We do **not** require $0\ne1$ for rings because we want any family of rings to have a product. But domains don't have (nontrivial) products anyway, so it is simpler to reject the "anomaly" $0=1$ for them.

Comment: But sir, I have taken this question from a book.

Comment: Which book? (In this kind of situation it would be better, I think, to mention the book in the question.)

Comment: Galois Theory by Ian Stewart

Comment: It is implicitely assumed that $f(1)=1$, i.e. that we are dealing with homomorphisms of rings with unity.

Comment: The 1 could still be 0.

Comment: @AdLibitum - Please look at darij's comment above. (In case you hadn't been notified.)

Comment: @Rattanverma - You're right, this is Exercise 17.2. Don't you agree that the statement is false?

Comment: Yes sir. Firstly I also thought that something is missing in the statement. But Jose Carlos Santos sir has given an explicit proof. Which I think is right.

Comment: Sir, in this book it is clearly mentioned on the page no. 164 that 1 is not equal to 0.

Comment: It all depends on the conventions adopted that are usually reported in the introduction or whereabouts. That "ring" means "commutative ring with unity such that $0\neq1$" is a widely adopted convention.

Comment: @AdLibitum - You say that $0\ne1$ is a widely adopted convention. How do you sustain this claim? I had never seen this convention before. (We want the category of commutative rings to have products.)

Comment: @Rattanverma - I don't think the convention $0\ne1$ is standard. (I also think there is a good reason for not adopting it, and I believe that this is the opinion of the vast majority of mathematicians.)

Comment: Yes sir, it is not standard convention. It the mentioned book, the main idea is taken over complex fields. So they have not considered general definition of rings.

Comment: @Rattanverma - I suggest you change your question to "Let $f: K \rightarrow R$ be a ring homomorphism, where $K$ is a field and $R$ is a nonzero commutative ring with unity. Prove that $f$ is one-to-one". (I added the word "nonzero".) (If you do so I'll edit my answer.)

Comment: Ok sir. Actually is according to this book, this assumption is included already. However, I will.mention it separately.

Comment: @Pierre-YvesGaillard: in some contexts it is. I remember as a student reading a book by Kaplansky (no less!) where all the results looked too good to be true. After being really puzzled I eventually found out that he was assuming "ring"$=$PID :) . I suppose that in a basic book about Galois theory, of which there are plenty, assuming that a ring is commutative with unity different from $0$ is not a great loss.